# jenkins handles condition unexpectedly

Tags: jenkins

I have a few condition commands in the jenkins script and it did not give my expected output, so I broke them down like this:

```
echo "PY38_RELEASE: ${env.PY38_RELEASE}"
echo "TAG_NAME: ${env.TAG_NAME}"
echo "TAG_NAME: ${env.TAG_NAME != null}"
echo "condition: ${env.PY38_RELEASE || env.TAG_NAME}"
echo "condition: ${env.PY38_RELEASE || env.TAG_NAME != null}"
```

Then I observe the output, and I got this:

```
[2024-03-14T02:18:14.115Z] PY38_RELEASE: false
[2024-03-14T02:18:14.125Z] TAG_NAME: null
[2024-03-14T02:18:14.135Z] TAG_NAME: false
[2024-03-14T02:18:14.145Z] condition: true
[2024-03-14T02:18:14.155Z] condition: true
```

I don't get it when the `env.PY38_RELEASE` is false and `env.TAG_NAME != null` is false, however their `OR` is true. Where did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what's going on is that the value of `env.PY38_RELEASE` is the *string* `'false'`, not the boolean value `false`.

What I would suggest is writing in your script:

```
def real_py38_release = env.PY38_RELEASE && (env.PY38_RELEASE != 'false')
```

And then in your conditions use `real_py38_release` where before you had `env.PY38_RELEASE`.

Comment: You are right. I printed the type of env.PY38_RELEASE and it shows: `The type of env.PY38_RELEASE is: String`. This is not what I expected because this parameter was first defined as bool in the Parameter section as: `booleanParam defaultValue: false, description: 'perform release python3.8', name: 'PY38_RELEASE'`